# Manage SQL session state using Azure AD

Tags: .net, sql-server, azure, session, azure-active-directory

We have an old .net web form application using SQL session management and membership module.
As per new directive we have to implement Azure AD for authentication. It's all done and completed.
Now the issue here is how to manage session state.
I know we can configure in Azure directly:[Manage session in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-session-lifetime)

But security team will not allow it and told us we need to use sql server(On-PREM, our sql server is not hosted in Azure) session management only.
I am able to get session entries in [ASPStateTempSessions]. 
But not able to achieve session timeout. I have set it for 20 mins but session never gets expired.

Thanks in advance for the help. :)

Comment: Hi winterishere, if my answer is helpful for you, could please mark it as answer? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Azure AD doesn't support on-premise SQL Server.

You can not using Azure AD to manage the session state.

Hope this helps.

Comment: correct.. Azure AD has it's own session state. And what surprises me is default is 180 days :)
This link helped too:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/a6eca16a-8452-4cb5-8bb6-7da686b0b8d1/azure-ad-session-timeout?forum=WindowsAzureAD